# Java 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

@ Gouki Pls check if this is a correct Implementation as there may be multiple attributes in my row that has T,N or X -I basically want to check if the first attribute in every row for a value of T,N or X and do some business logic-  Thanks

```
public void printarray(List<String[]> usersList)     {  
  for(String[] row: usersList) {

      System.out.println(row[0]);

if(row[0].equals("N")){
System.out.println("Insert records in DB");
System.out.println("*********************");
System.out.println(row[1]+" , " + row[2]+" , "+row[3]+" , " + row[4]+" " +row[5]);
}
     if(row[0].equals("T")){
System.out.println("Get date from DB and update DB based on the same");
System.out.println("*********************");
System.out.println(row[1]+" , " + row[2]+" , "+row[3]+" , " + row[4]+" " +row[5]);
}
     if(row[0].equals("X")){
System.out.println("Update 2 sub tables");
System.out.println("*********************");
System.out.println(row[1]+" , " + row[2]+" , "+row[3]+" , " + row[4]+" " +row[5]);
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perhaps use a List as container for every row (which is an array).

```
List<String[]> userList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

and then on your while loop:

```
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] values = line.split(",");
        userList.add(values);
  }
```

To retrieve, modify your printarray :

```
public void printarray(List<String[]> usersList)
    {

        for(String[] row: usersList) {
            for(String element:row) {
                System.out.println(element);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you put `values` directly into `userList`?

Comment: Also consider `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: @marcelo, you're right, i overlooked that. Will update answer

Comment: @ In ur updated answe pls help me with populating in userlist itself and retrieving it as well Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @user549432 , I've updated the answer to demonstrate how to retrieve the data from the list. It functions just the same as your original method (print the elements)

Comment: @Gouki Thanks a lot for your answer - It worked perfectly and this is exactly what I want - Really appreciate it

Comment: @ Gouki In my earlier Implementation I had checks for the 5 the element for every row to be a particular value out of 3 values N,T or a X i.e userArray[i][5]="N" then some business logic to be done - where i is the row and 5 is the column - Can you pls validate if  how this is what to be done in this print array - Thanks Gouki for all your help

Comment: @ Gouki The reason why I ask this question is there might be more than one attribute that can have a value N,T or X in a row -

Comment: @user549432 You should add another question if you need further help. This is to not make this answer confusing to other people.